# knockout.js: pass { data: xyz } to foreach instead of just xyz

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm just getting started with knockout.js. I have a `foreach` binding like this, which works fine:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
   <li> .... </li>
</ul>
```

`people` is part of my model that I pass to `ko.applyBindings`. According to the documentation, the following should work too:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: {data: people}">
```

But it does not. The list remains empty, but I don't see any error in the error window of my browser. Any hint what I might be doing wrong? Is there some subtle difference between both calls which I don't see?

My idea is to pass handlers for `afterAdd` to `foreach`. Therefore I need the second way to call it.

Comment: At first sight, it seems that it should work ok. Besides that, knockout has a big try-catch somewhere that's probably hiding the error messages (had that problem a few times), look it up in the code and set your own breakpoint, maybe that'll help you to find the issue.

Comment: The binding change shouldn't give the effect you're seeing with all other code unchanged, the behavior should be exactly the same. Did you change anything else at the same time?

Comment: This could be a lot of things, a fiddle will help a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the records: The solution is a bit strange and the source of the problem was another error in my code. `people` is initialized via `ko.observableArray`. When I got new data from the server, I udated my model like this:

```
model.people(ko.observableArray(newData));
```

Now I know that the this is the correct way to do it:

```
model.people(newData);
```

For whatever reason, the first version still works with certain template binding specifications, but not for all. The second one works fine in every case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are actually looking for the template binding. Foreach is a shortcut onto it, but if you need afterAdd you could use the full binding:

```
<ul data-bind='template: { foreach: people,
                        afterAdd: myPostProcessingLogic }'> </ul>
```